# Excel VBA - Change entire workbook's cells that are shaded blue to green

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that contains multiple sheets of various data where some rows (ie. alternating) are shaded/filled with blue. I need VBA code that changes all blue shaded cells across the entire workbook to be shaded another color (green). Every blue shaded cell is the 'same' blue color for reference.

Any suggestions for the most efficient way to do this in one go? Open to ideas.

Answer (score 0):

### Appy Interior Color To Rows

- Adjust the constants and the workbook.
- Note that 'one go' (`tRng.Interior.color = InteriorColor`) can be applied only to one worksheet at a time.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub applyInteriorRows()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const NthRow As Long = 2
    Const InteriorColor As Long = 14348258
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tRng As Range
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange
        RowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
        If RowsCount >= FirstRow Then
            Set tRng = rng.Rows(FirstRow)
            If RowsCount >= FirstRow + NthRow Then
                For i = FirstRow + NthRow To RowsCount Step NthRow
                    Set tRng = Union(tRng, rng.Rows(i))
                Next i
            Else
                ' Too few rows: only first row changed.
            End If
            tRng.Interior.color = InteriorColor
        Else
            ' Too few rows: no changes.
        End If
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Interior color applied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```